# How to get second record onwards

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Using SQL Server 2000

table1

```
id date time

001 01/02/2012 02:00
001 02/02/2012 01:00
001 07/02/2012 08:00
002 04/02/2012 01:00
002 15/02/2012 06:00
...
```

from the table1 i want to get the second record onwards for each id order by date column

Expected Output

```
id date time

001 02/02/2012 01:00
001 07/02/2012 08:00
002 15/02/2012 06:00
...
```

How to make a query for getting the second record onwards.

Need sql query help

Comment: @marc_s, i edited my question, order by date column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like

```
SELECT  yt.*
FROM    your_table yt INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  [id],
                    MIN([datetime]) first_datetime
            FROM    your_table
            GROUP BY    [id]
        ) f ON  yt.id = f.id
            AND yt. [datetime] > f.first_datetime
```

Assuming *first record* is the min date per ID.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the data looks like it's not orderer by time, so it will complicate things a little.
I dont have a SQL Server 2000 to try this out, so I will try to comment each line so you get the idea and correct any errors:

Create a new temp table with an identity column

```
create #tmp (MYNEWID int identity, id int, dt datetime)
```

insert records from you table

```
insert into #tmp select id, dt from table1
```

get every record except the first id:

```
select id, dt 
from #tmp T 
where cast(T.id as varchar)+cast(T.dt as varchar) not in 
    (select top 1 cast(X.id as varchar)+cast(X.dt as varchar) 
    from #tmp X 
    where T.id=X.id 
    order by MYNEWID asc)
```

The following code will not work as expected if there are duplicate dt's

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.* from table1 t1 left join 
(select top 1 * from table1) t2
on t1.id=t2.id and t1.date=t2.date and t1.time=t2.time
where t2.id is null and t2.date is null and t2.time is null
```